# Filter on categorical (Interval) column using pandas df.query()

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter a `dataframe` with `object` and `interval` `category` columns. I want to filter on multiple conditions. How can I do that with `interval` `category` data?

The `query` function returns multiple intervals.

```
>>> my_df
        vtype   velocity_bin
0         car  (-0.001, 5.0]
1         car    (5.0, 10.0]
2         car    (10.0, inf]
3  motorcycle  (-0.001, 5.0]
4  motorcycle    (5.0, 10.0]
>>> my_df.dtypes
vtype             object
velocity_bin    category
dtype: object
>>> my_df.query('vtype == "car" & velocity_bin == (5, 10)')
  vtype   velocity_bin
0   car  (-0.001, 5.0]
1   car    (5.0, 10.0]
```

I expect the output to be

```
  vtype   velocity_bin
1   car    (5.0, 10.0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "velocity_bin" column is comprised of Interval objects. This poses some degree of challenge because `query` does not easily support it.

As the idiomatic solution, I recommend,

```
df[(df['vtype'] == 'car') & (df['velocity_bin'] == pd.Interval(5, 10))]
```

However, as with anything else, you can hack together a `query` solution. Using the `"python"` engine and converting "velocity_bin" to string for a string comparison, we have

```
df.query(
    'vtype="car" and velocity_bin.astype("str") == "(5.0, 10.0]"', engine='python')
```

Comment: didnt know we can call `astype()` under `query()` , that's a nice flex to have :)